# Sort alphabetically from A to Z table (database)

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I'm currently working on an update of my Android application. I have hundred recipes already entered in the data table. I want to sort them alphabetically (ASC).
I tried a code that I applied in my case on `SQLLITEMANAGER` on Firefox and I executed manipulation and indeed, it classified them, but not on Eclipse, I set:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_recipes<br />
ORDER BY recipe_name ASC;
```

Please, where can I put the code in my Android project?